# Pressing button to make a thread do its work

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton

I have a class named `Card` and this class extends `Thread`
so I have an override of the method `run()` and it says:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        while (Bingobtn == pressed) {
            System.out.println("Thread working is: " + this.ID);
            this.d.getDetails(size, this, frmBingo);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(d);
            t1.start();
            Bingobtn = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I initialize `static Bingobtn = 0` and `static pressed =1`, so I have a button in this class (`Card`) whenever I press the button I gave an `action:istener` that `Bingobtn=1`;

```
Bbtn = new JButton("Bingo");
Bbtn.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
Bbtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Castellar", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 22));
Bbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Bingobtn = 1;               
    }
});
```

But the problem here that the `while(Bingobtn == pressed)` never is true, even I press the bingo button... it's like the `Bingobtn` never equals 1!

Comment: Are you sure your action listener got invoked on button click? Better to add a print statement before setting the value of `Bingobtn` to 1. Also, in times like this I suggest instead of setting `Bingobtn` to 1, rather spawn the thread inside the `actionPerformed` method or making use of Simple Wait-Notify.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Given there is no MCVE / SSCCE, I cannot be sure, but.. Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 3) `static` declaration of methods or attributes is rarely necessary, and often causes more problems than it solves. 4_ Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, ..

Comment: .. `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: what is the value of `pressed`?

Comment: Why don't you put the `public void run() ` method in a `class SomeRunnable implements Runnable` remove the `while (true) { while ( ...`, also remove the `new Thread` in that while loop and in the `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` you call `new Thread(new SomeRunnable())`?

Comment: @michaeak because when I create obejcts of class cards in the main() I do: for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {card c[i] = new card(); c[i].start();}
 like if I dont do start to the c[i] then how could c[i] be a thread and be waiting for me to press the button..   and the value of pressed is 1 and it doesn't change in the whole program...like i just dont know why the Bingobtn != 1 even when i click the button and print the result of Bingobtn and its says Bingobtn = 1..

Comment: Are both the `ActionListener actionPerformed(...)` and the `run()` methods referring to the same `Bingobtn`?

Comment: @michaeak yes, for sure.

Comment: If you write `System.out.println(Bingobtn)` between  the `while` loops of the `run()` method, what does it say? Did you start the thread?

Comment: @michaeak yeah I did start the thread in the main, and I tried now to print the value of Bingobtn and it is always equal to 0.. even when I press the JButton with an action performed for Bingobtn to be equal to 1

Comment: @michaeak put when i added that print linebetween the while loops in the run() method i just noticed that it started to work... like now when ever i click the button the while(Bingobtn == 1) is returning true and the thread works,,, but why ? i dont understand why when i added that print like the Bingobtn variable started to change.

Comment: @michaeak Look, i dont understand why, and how but its works now ! , i just added a try/catch {} in the run() method after the while(true) loop and before the while(Bingobtn == 1)  it says try {
   Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
I think that it was illegal to start a thread and make him do nothing and wait for an action... but I'm not sure about that at all..

Comment: @Fadi If you start a `Thread` which has `nothing to do` which means it is not doing anything or waiting for anything it would just finish, no problem.